# Placeholder Text Changing on Button Click & Bootstrap Validation of Changed Placeholder Text on Clicking Submit

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm very new to web development and could do with a wee bit of help on validation.
I am currently designing a form for a website being built using Bootstrap.
As you can see from the code you get 3 buttons numbered 1, 2 & 3, 3 inputs, a name input and there is also a submit button at the end.
Currently when you press 1, 2 or 3 it only changes the placeholder text in the "First Choice" input box.
What I need help with is:
The buttons can be used on any of the 3 placeholders;

```
    1. If "First Choice" is already selected (placeholder text has changed) then select "Second Choice", if "Second Choice" is selected (placeholder text has changed) then select "Third Choice".
    
    or (not sure which one of these I'll use yet)
    
    2. Any button can be used again if already selected to change any of the 3 placeholder text inputs.
    
    3. How do I validate if all 3 inputs have been changed on clicking submit?
    
    4. How do I validate the name input has been filled in?
    
    5. How do I validate if all 4 inputs have been changed on submitting?
    
    6. Am I doing this correctly? Or is there a simpler way?
```

Apologies if this is a lot of questions just trying to get my head around it all.

```
    Hope you can help
    
    Daz
```

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>

button {
    margin:50px 0 50px 0;
}
.container {
    border:solid black 1px;
    width:60%;
}
#f2, #f3, #f4, #f6 {
    text-align:center;
}

#f5 {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="changePlaceholder1()">1</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="changePlaceholder2()"> 2</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" onclick="changePlaceholder3()">3</button>
    <br>    
    <input id="f2" readonly placeholder="First Choice">
    <input id="f3" readonly placeholder="Second Choice">
    <input id="f4" readonly placeholder="Third Choice"><br>
    <br>
    <input id="f6" type="name" placeholder="Name">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function changePlaceholder1() { 
        selectedTextarea = $('#f2')[0]; 

        selectedTextarea.placeholder = "1";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function changePlaceholder2() { 
        selectedTextarea = $('#f2')[0]; 

        selectedTextarea.placeholder = "2"; 
}
</script>
<script>
    function changePlaceholder3() { 
        selectedTextarea = $('#f2')[0]; 

        selectedTextarea.placeholder = "3";
}
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000331/placeholder-text-changing-on-button-click-bootstrap-validation-of-changed-plac#) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For none-related code questions visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you have more than 1 question you should split the post. You questions are unclear and messy.

Comment: Your question is not related to bootstrap but javascript and jqueryn, you should add those tags to maximise your chances

Comment: Hi Amarinediary, many thanks for the advice and guidance I'll break it down and repost. Cheers